# Bash script size limitation?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, rhel6

I have a bash script that, when run on RHEL or OS X, gives the following error:

> line 62484: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
>
> line 62484: `     -o_gz'

This is an auto-generated script to work around a limitation introduced by the grid engine compute cluster used in my company. It is all composed of a bunch of almost-identical `if/elif`'s. I can't see anything special with the line where the error comes from. When I run the beginning part of the script before the error line, it works without problems. This makes me think that there may be some bash script length limitation. The only reference I could find on the web was the [comment by *iAdjunct*](https://askubuntu.com/a/205798/574083).

The part of the script around the error looks like this (with some simplifications):

```
.
.
.
.
elif [ $task_number -eq 2499 ]
then
    /some/tool/executable \
    -use_prephased_g \
    -m \  
    /some/text/file \
    -h \  
    /some/zipped/file \
    -l \  
    -int \
     45063854 \
     46063853 \
    -Ne \ 
     20000 \
    -o \  
    /some/output/file \
    -verbose \
    -o_gz #==============> ****THIS IS LINE 62484****
elif [ $task_number -eq 2500 ]
then
    /some/tool/executable \
    -use_prephased_g \
    -m \  
    /some/other/text/file \
    -h \  
    /some/other/zipped/file \
    -l \  
    -int \
     98232182 \
     99232182 \
    -Ne \ 
     20000 \
    -o \  
    /some/other/output/file \
    -verbose \
    -o_gz
elif [ $task_number -eq 2501 ] 
.
.
.
.
```

Does this ring any bells for anyone?

Comment: try http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: If the only difference between the `elif`s is *$task_number* and the three *-int* and *-Ne* numbers, and the `-m` and `-h` filenames, then it's in effect a function that inputs one variable, and returns three numbers and two filenames.  It'd be simpler to put all four numbers and two filenames in a table or array, make a function to return the desired conditional output, then the script wouldn't need *any* `if`s or `elif`s for that -- one function call would do the work of thousands of `elif`s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is a limitation with `bash`.

It's not a script size limit; rather it's a limit to the depth of the parser stack, which has the effect of restricting the complexity of certain constructs. In particular, it will restrict the number of `elif` clauses in an `if` statement to about 2500.

There is a longer analysis of this problem with respect to a different syntactic construct (iterated pipes) in my answer to [a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185923/24557) on the [Unix & Linux stackexchange](http://unx.stackexchange.com/) site.

`case` statements don't have this limitation, and the sample you provide certainly looks like a good match for a `case` statement.

(The difference with `case` statements is that the grammar for `if` conditional statements, like that of pipe constructs, is right recursive, while the grammar for `case` statements is left recursive. The reason the limitation on `if` statements is different from the limitation on pipes is that the grammatical construct for an `elif` clause has one more symbol, so each repetition uses four stack slots rather than three.)

If the `case` statement doesn't work for you -- or even if it does -- you could try building a precompiled binary search tree of `if` statements:

```
if (( task_number < 8 )); then
  if (( task_number < 4 )); then
    if (( task_number < 2 )); then
      if (( task_number < 1)); then
        # do task 0
      else
        # do task 1
      fi;
    elif (( task_number < 3 )); then
      # do task 2
    else
      # do task 3
    fi
  elif (( task_number < 6 )); then
    if (( task_number < 5 )); then
      # do task 4
    else
      # do task 5
    fi
  elif (( task_number < 7 )); then
    # do task 6
  else
    # do task 7
  fi
elif (( task_number < 12 )); then
  if (( task_number < 10 )); then
    if (( task_number < 9 )); then
      # do task 8
    else
      # do task 9
    fi
  elif (( task_number < 11 )); then
    # do task 10
  else
    # do task 11
  fi
elif (( task_number < 14 )); then
  if (( task_number < 13 )); then
    # do task 12
  else
    # do task 13
  fi
elif (( task_number < 15 )); then
  # do task 14
else
  # do task 15
fi
```

Because each complete `if` statement only occupies a single stack node after it is recognized, the complexity limitation will be on the nesting depth of the `if` statements rather than the number of clauses. As an additional bonus, it will execute a lot fewer comparisons in the average case.

If you have no alternative other than a sequential list of conditions, you can use separate `if` statements:

```
while :; do
  if condition1; then
    # do something
  break; fi; if condition2; then
    # do something
  break; fi; if condition3; then
    # do something
  break; fi; if condition4; then
    # do something
  break; fi
  # No alternative succeeded
  break
done
```

The unconventional indent is intended to illustrate the simple program transformation: simply replace every `elif` with `break;fi;if` and surround the whole thing with a `while` (to provide the target for the `break`s.)

Comment: Just tested `bash` v4.3 with a 10 million line (250 megs) script: `for f in {1..10000000} ; do echo 'echo '"$f"' > /dev/null' ; done >> big.sh ; bash big.sh`.  It worked fine.  Edited answer to be a little more definite on this *not* being a script maximun number of lines problem.